# Blocking and Non-blocking I/Os in C++ definition and implementation

Tags: c++, io, nonblocking

Recently due to a c++ project I'm dealing with I came across the concept of Non-blocking I/Os in C++. 
If someone needs a cross-platform solution, can the non-blocking mode be implemented without the use of boost.asio , libuv and any relevant external library? An example would be quite helpful to distinguish the difference between blocking and non-blocking I/O.

Comment: "I/Os" is not a thing; you probably mean I/O.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "STL"?

Comment: Non-blocking I/O and threads are orthogonal: You can have either with and without the other.

Comment: Do you have a concrete question? What exactly is ambiguous, contradictory, or blurry?

Comment: "*sharing opinions and experiences on [...] generic issues*" is not what SO is for. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: @melpomene Ys I meant I/O. By STL I meant Standard Template Library. Regading ambiguity I found forum answers that proposing multi-threading a prerequisite for non-blocking I/O  and others not. Also blurry is that sometimes it was referred as Asynchronous I/O and not non-blocking. And you are right about sharing opinions and experiences on [...] generic issues" I'll rephrase it.

Comment: OK, what exactly do you mean by "Standard Template Library"?

Comment: (I'm asking because the STL *is* an external library. Parts of it were added to the standard C++ library, but not all of it, and many standard C++ headers are not from the STL.)

Comment: @melpomene  I mean perhaps the use of elements of iostream library like ostream, stringstream, streambuf etc.

Comment: @melpomene So for example the use istream::read() is blocking and istream::readsome() is a non-blocking one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I/O - in any computational sense - takes time. Where this time is used is determined by whether an I/O operation is "blocking" or "non-blocking".

Non-blocking I/O takes place out of the calling thread. This usually means a "busy wait" for a signal from the I/O telling you there is data.

Blocking I/O operations will halt execution of the calling thread until the operation is done.

For network sockets:

- Non-blocking read operations will be "instant" and you will need to poll the socket for information on whether it has finished reading and if so, the size of the data that was read.
- Blocking read operations will wait until data has been read before unwaiting.

For files:
Similar case to network sockets only you are reading from a hardware device so its probably going to be quicker.

As for multithreading, it is a vicious beast to work with. As a rule of thumb it shouldnt be in your vocabulary of C++ terminology unless you absolutely need it.

Comment: I can't remember the last time I had to code a "busy wait". This is not the usual way to do things. Also, what exactly do you mean by "*you will need to poll the socket for information on whether it has finished reading and if so, the size of the data that was read*"?

Comment: To be honest I dont have commercial or professional experience. I've used network sockets from SFML (Simple/Fast Media Library) and if you decide to use a non-blocking socket, you need to call a function to return the status of the socket. As for the busy wait, it was from my experience using one for Open Steamworks to process events.